Zip File Upload in PowerApps to PostgreSQL Database
iam trying to upload a Zip File into a PostgreSQL Database using the PowerApps Connector and PowerAutomate.
I kindof reach a brickwall here, I do not find alot about this in the web and have no Idea how to approach this ideally.
I thought of converting the Zip file into a JSON string, and then upload it via Automate, but the files can get to upwards of 5GB and i dont know if that is still possible then.
Iam very thankful for your experiences with this and ideas.
Cheers!
Various import executions in Powerapps

Are you sure you want to store a file in a database? A file system is the natural solution for files, not a database. Just store the file name and path in the database and the file itself on (virtual) disk.
